# Element of the group raise to power 1.

Tags: group-theory

If I have a group with operation modulo 2 containing element 3. What would be the value of $3^1$?

Will it be 3 or 1 as 3 modulo 2=1 ?

Comment: What group are you talking about, specifically? If it's something isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $3$ is not even in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, the group $\mathbb Z_2$ contains $2$ elements: 
$\overline 0 = 0 + 2\mathbb Z = \{ 0+2z: z \in \mathbb Z \}$ and
$\overline 1 = 1 + 2\mathbb Z = \{ 1+2z: z \in \mathbb Z \}$. In that sense, 
$\overline 1 = \overline 3 = \left(\overline 1 \right)^1 =
 \left(\overline 3 \right)^1$.

Edit due to @drhab's comments

$\mathbb Z_2$ is only a group with respect to addition. The structure
$[\mathbb Z_2, +]$ is a group and the structure $[\mathbb Z_2, \cdot]$ is not because, for example, $\overline 0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

For the group $[\mathbb Z_2, +]$, the notation $\overline x^1$ makes no sense.  But $1\overline x$ does and $1\overline x = \overline x$.

However, the structure $[\mathbb Z_2, +, \cdot]$ is a ring and, because $2$ is a prime number, it is even a field. In that sense,
$\overline 1^1 =\overline 3^1 = \overline 1$ but $\overline 0^1$ is still undefined.

Comment: Is it true that $a^1 = a$ for any element $a$ belonging to the group under any operation?

Comment: This is true in any group and even in any semigroup.

Comment: @RajeshR In abelian groups normally additional notation is practicized. That means that e.g. we write $2a$ instead of $a^2$. In that context the notation $a^1$ is switched for $1a$ (so then it makes no sense to ask for the meaning of $a^1$). Multiplicative notation gives: $a^1=a$ and additional notation gives: $1a=a$.

Comment: @drhab You're right. Now what the heck do I do?

Comment: Your concern ;-). Maybe an edit to clarify what's wrong here.